# Python Scrapy coming back blank

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Trying to make a web scraper for this site: https://stats.nba.com/search/team-game/#?sort=GAME_DATE&dir=1&Season=2019-20

here I want the scraper to go and pull the data for each NBA game that is posted.  Right now I'm just trying to get it to pull the name of the team playing (first column).  However, I'm getting a blank json file back when I try to run the the spider.

Here's my code:

```
import scrapy

class TeamsDataScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "teamdata"

    #def start_requests(self):
    urls = ["http://stats.nba.com/search/team-game/#?sort=GAME_DATE&dir=1&Season=2019-20"]

        #for url in urls:
    #yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for team in response.xpath("//td[@class='player-name text']"):
            yield{
                'teamName': team.xpath(".//td[@class='player-name text']/a/text()").extract_first()
            }
```

Comment: Your code sample isn't clear - why is `start_requests` commented out? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Its because your scraper does not have any entry point at all

You must have either of below

1. A list named `start_urls` (change `urls` to `start_urls` in your code)
2. `start_requests` method that `yield` one or more `scrapy.Request` objects